# The ball does not come out of the barrel of the rifle according to where the player is moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The ball does not come out of the barrel of the rifle according to where the player is moving

```
`void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.C))
    {
        Instantiate (bool_gun.transform, bool_.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    }`
```

Comment: Add more details so that it will easy to understand your question.

Comment: But the instantiate works? cause you are passing transform, position and identity, but the firm of the functions requires the Object to instantiate if I understood the doc: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html

Comment: so... where's your question?

Answer (score 0):

In case you're trying to instantiate a new bullet coming out of a riffle that the player is carrying, you'll have to instantiate the prefab at the position where the riffle is currently located, NOT the position that the prefab has stored, which is something that does not change at runtime, but is just statically set in your prefab

```
void Update () {
if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.C))
{
   Instantiate (bool_gun_PREFAB, PLAYER_(RIFFLE)_POSITION, Quaternion.LookDirection(PLAYER_(RIFFLE)_FORWARD));
}
```

If you can actually put a question-mark in your question and clearly state what you are trying to achieve, how you do it, what goes wrong and what you have tried, we can maybe help you further

Comment: I didn't realize what you did.

Comment: nor did we what you did. Again: If you can actually put a question-mark in your question and clearly state what you are trying to achieve, how you do it, what goes wrong and what you have tried, we can maybe help you further

Answer (score 0):

Not much information to work with, but, if I were writing this I would create a empty game object called bullet spawn, make it a child of the rifle, adjust it to the end of the barrel, and set that as your transform.position.